# How can we attract users who don't categorize themselves as programmers?

Tags: discussion

Jon Ericson makes an interesting point [in his recent answer](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/88) (well, really, just reiterates the same point he's been making for weeks, albeit not an insubstantial one): In order to become a successful site, we need to have a solid reason why **asking your Vim questions on vi.SE is considerably *better* than asking them on Stack Overflow**. Specifically:

> I'm left wondering who is served by this site who would not be served by leaving Vi[m] questions where they are now.

Perhaps a bit severe, but again, it is an argument: **If we want a real community, we need to be able to draw in users who don't classify themselves as programmers**. Otherwise, why not just ask on Stack Overflow?

This might be more of a question for when we reach public beta, but it doesn't hurt to ask now. Even this early in the site's development, a whopping *31 out of 36* of our [top users](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) have Stack Overflow as one of their top 5 network accounts. How do we plan to attract users who aren't using Vim for programming?

Comment: I've always thought of vi (vim less so) as primarily a sysadmin's editor. What can this site offer to sysadmins?

Comment: @Gilles It can answer their questions about using vi for sysadmin tasks! ;)

Answer (score 7):

If I look at the
[Area51 commitment page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80441?page=5&phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top)
, I see:

```
committers active in
64.8% Stack Overflow
21.1% Super User
16.7% Unix & Linux
14.8% Meta Stack Overflow
14.8% Vi and Vim
13.7% Meta Stack Exchange
```

And the commitment text reads as follows:

> commit to participate actively in Vi and Vim for at least three months,
>   especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten
>   questions.

This means that right now, about 35% of the people who signed up for vi.SE are
*not* active on StackOveflow and at least have the *intention* of being active
here.

This doesn't necessarily say anything about these people's occupation of course,
they could be a programmer, accountant, or lion tamer. There is no way for us to
know, but what we do know is that they're *not* asking questions or answering
them on StackOverflow

There are some things we can do in our answers to make this a more friendly
place for non-technical users in general:

- Don't assume programming knowledge in answers or questions.
- Don't assume in-depth knowledge about the OS (Linux/UNIX, OSX, or Windows). In
  fact, don't simple *assume* the user is using Linux or OSX.
- Similarly, don't assume in-depth knowledge of commandline tools and such.

Comment: I'll have to get used to shaking off that second assumption.

Comment: ^ Same. The vi ecosystem is almost synonymous with the *nix ecosystem, but it's also available on Windows. That's about the only thing that kept me sane when I had to take a class on Windows Server administration.